# Moving to next tab from inside the current tab

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to build a multi-tab form, where the navbar at the top both serves as progress tracker and navigation to previous tabs.
I'm having 2 issues with the "Next" behavior:

1. It hides the previous tab and shows the next tab below the 1st tab
2. The navbar at the top doesn't update to show which is the current tab

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>{{settings.title}}</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, viewport-fit=cover" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./customcss/sidebar.css">
</head>

<body>
  {{> headers/main_header}}
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <main class="col-md-9 ms-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-md-4">
{{> sidebars/Sidebar1}}
  <ul class="nav nav-pills pt-2 pb-2 justify-content-center" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
      <button class="nav-link active disabled" id="nav-tab1-step" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-tab1" type="button" role="tab">Tab 1</button>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
      <button class="nav-link disabled" id="nav-tab2-step" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-tab2" type="button" role="tab">Tab 2</button>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
      <button class="nav-link disabled" id="nav-tab3-step" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-tab3" type="button" role="tab">Tab 3</button>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
      <button class="nav-link disabled" id="nav-tab4-step" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-tab4" type="button" role="tab">Tab 4</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
  <form name="stackDeployment" method="post">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-tab1" role="tabpanel">
      <div class="mb-3">
        <h1 class="h2">Tab 1</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="form-floating mb-3">
        <select name="selectedItem" id="selectedItem" class="form-select">
          <option selected>Select an Item</option>
          {{#each item}}
            <option value="{{this.itemName}}">{{this.itemName}}</option>
            {{/each}}
          </select>
          <label for="selectedItem">Item ID</label>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
              <button class="nav-link" id="nav-tab2-step" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-tab2" type="button" role="tab">Next</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-tab2" role="tabpanel">
        <div class="mb-3">
          <h1 class="h2">Tab 2</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
          <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
          <label for="name">Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
          <input name="surname" type="text" class="form-control" id="surname">
          <label for="surname">Surname</label>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
          <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
            <button class="nav-link" id="nav-tab3-step" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-tab3" type="button" role="tab">Next</button>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-tab3" role="tabpanel">
        <div class="mb-3">
          <h1 class="h2">Unfinished Tab 3</h1>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
          <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
            <button class="nav-link" id="nav-tab4-step" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-tab4" type="button" role="tab">Next</button>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-tab4" role="tabpanel">
        <div class="mb-3">
          <h1 class="h2">Unfinished Tab 4</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
  </form>
</div>
</main>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script language="javascript" src="./bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "It hides the previous tab and shows the next tab below the 1st tab"

The problem is the tab-panes should be the immediate child of `tab-content`...

```
      <main class="col-md-9 ms-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-md-4">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills pt-2 pb-2 justify-content-center" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
                <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                    <button class="nav-link active disabled" id="nav-tab1-step" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-tab1" type="button" role="tab">Tab 1</button>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                    <button class="nav-link disabled" id="nav-tab2-step" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-tab2" type="button" role="tab">Tab 2</button>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                    <button class="nav-link disabled" id="nav-tab3-step" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-tab3" type="button" role="tab">Tab 3</button>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                    <button class="nav-link disabled" id="nav-tab4-step" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-tab4" type="button" role="tab">Tab 4</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div id="nav-tabContent">
                <form name="stackDeployment" class="tab-content" method="post">
                    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-tab1" role="tabpanel">
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <h1 class="h2">Tab 1</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                            <select name="selectedItem" id="selectedItem" class="form-select">
                                <option selected>Select an Item</option>
                                {{#each item}}
                                    <option value="{{this.itemName}}">{{this.itemName}}</option>
                                {{/each}}
                            </select>
                            <label for="selectedItem">Item ID</label>
                        </div>
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
                            <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                                <button class="nav-link" id="nav-tab2-step" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-tab2" type="button" role="tab">Next</button>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-tab2" role="tabpanel">
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <h1 class="h2">Tab 2</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                            <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
                            <label for="name">Name</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                            <input name="surname" type="text" class="form-control" id="surname">
                            <label for="surname">Surname</label>
                        </div>
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
                            <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                                <button class="nav-link" id="nav-tab3-step" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-tab3" type="button" role="tab">Next</button>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-tab3" role="tabpanel">
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <h1 class="h2">Unfinished Tab 3</h1>
                        </div>
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
                            <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                                <button class="nav-link" id="nav-tab4-step" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-tab4" type="button" role="tab">Next</button>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-tab4" role="tabpanel">
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <h1 class="h2">Unfinished Tab 4</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
      </main>
```

[Bootstrap 5 - Next Tab from inside another Tab's content](https://codeply.com/p/1QkyyHt8vE)

> "The navbar at the top doesn't update to show which is the current
> tab"

To highlight the nav tabs when navigated to from another tab...

```
var tabEl = document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="pill"]')
tabEl.forEach((t)=>{
    t.addEventListener('show.bs.tab', function(event) {
        var triggerEl = event.target
        var dataAttr = triggerEl.getAttribute("data-bs-target")
        var tab = document.querySelector('[data-bs-target="'+dataAttr+'"]')
        tab.click()
    })
})
```

Comment: This solved the issue with the tabs wonderfully but unfortunately, the navbar still doesn't update to show which tab are you on.

Comment: You have to programmatically do that. Using separate Nav items to change the tabs aren't going to automatically change the tabs nav.